# Database design need better solution many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like:

```
classes:id,time_instructor_id

instructors:id,name
```

I want each instructors to have one or many classes which is fine with my current design...

What for ex in the future one instructors leaves the job and another one can substitute that instructor, how do I assign the class to the new Instructor?

I was thinking in this case if I could have a N:N table?

What is your opinion?

Comment: You are correct, a many-to-many relationship, using a join-table, would be appropriate here.

Comment: @willOEM I disagree; I think you jumped to a conclusion about a Many-To-Many. Read the Question strictly, then read [the Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31642677/642706) by Larry Lustig.

Comment: @BasilBourque: I disagree, for exactly the reasons you laid out in your comment to the accepted answer.  Better to support the M:M scenario with necessary constraints for control than to assume that a realistically likely scenario will never take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no problem.  If an instructor leaves and another instructor is added and takes over the first instructor's classes you can simply `UPDATE` the `instructor_id` value for those classes with the new instructor's id.

You do not need a many-to-many table unless you want to be able to assign more than one instructor per class.

Is there more to your requirement than stated in your question?

Comment: Strictly speaking, directly answering the requirements as defined in the Question, this answer is correct. Practically speaking, for such a project in the real world, you would likely have occasions where you have more than one instructor co-teaching or you may decide to track the history of the substitution of teachers. Then you have a Many-To-Many relationship thereby needing the third table `teaching` to bridge.

Comment: You're right that a "real-life" implementation would most likely have a number of requirements that aren't present in the original question but absent those requirements I'd always go for the simplest solution.  Refactoring to provide an intermediate table will not be difficult if and when those requirements are added.

Comment: I totally understand and support what you were doing: strictly following the problem as stated. I just added a comment so other readers would understand why the difference between your Answer and the others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create third table called classes_instructors (this might depend on the framework conventions) which will have two attributes, maybe 3rd one to show whether is it active.

```
id
class_id
instructor_id
active
```

This is pretty common schema and pattern to use a many-to-many relationship through a join table. Some people tend to call it associative table or entity [many-to-many relation](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20ERwin%20Data%20Modeler%20r8-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/Methods/index.htm?toc.htm?254546.html).